# AchartEngine simple animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, achartengine

Would it b possible using the achartengine library to make it so that when a graph is plotted it makes it look like animated like in case of column charts columns are generated from bottom of the screen slowly moving upward?

Comment: Did you by any chance archive this animation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have dynamic charts meaning that you add data at runtime and then update the chart, but you cannot have animations in AChartEngine as it is out of the box.